# Installing Older FFmpeg Version Using Homebrew

Tags: video, ffmpeg, reaper

I have the latest version of Homebrew and FFmpeg on OSX 10.9.5.

I need to install an older version of FFmpeg using Homebrew, rather than just running:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Could someone please explain how to do this? I know older versions of FFmpeg are readily available online: just need to figure out how to get Homebrew to find them, either online or on my system after downloading.

MF.

Comment: Why do you want an older version? It is highly recommended that you use the latest available.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Comment: I'm running Reaper audio DAW, which requires FFmpeg libraries to render videos and decode videos properly. I recently installed the latest FFmpeg, and this has caused a range of problems. Since I'm in the middle of a sound design project, I'm hoping that reinstalling the old FFmpeg will resolve the issue, but something tells me it might be more complicated than that...

Comment: I'm also facing problem with latest ffmpeg version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611998/strange-libavformat-dependency-with-jackmp?noredirect=1#comment47387128_29611998

Comment: I also want to use an older version. FFMPEG is the worst maintained software in the world and it is impossible to port old code to work with a newer API without spending weeks or months figuring it out by trial and error (no porting guide, examples that only use the most basic parts of the API). I have code that I know works on an older version and don't want to reimplement 1000s of lines of code. Maintaining code to use the latest verison of FFMPEG at all times is a luxury most people don't have.

Answer (score 1):

You can install 4.4.2 with:

```
brew install ffmpeg@4
```

However, this seems to be the only older version available via brew (you will have to build from source if you need an older or more specific version than 4.4.2).