# Strange libavformat dependency with Jackmp

Tags: ffmpeg, dependencies, jack

I try to execute my application on another Mac than my development machine and I have the following error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
    Library not loaded: /System/Library/Framework/Versions/A/Jackmp
    Referenced from: /Volumes/FFmpegTest_v1.0.1/FFmpegTest.app/Contents/Frameworks/libavformat.56.dylib
```

It seems that this *Jackmp* library is a new dependency (not present in earlier *libavformat* dependencies) as I can check with:

```
otool -L /usr/local/lib/libavformat.dylib
```

Any idea?

Comment: What's the output of `otool -L /Volumes/FFmpegTest_v1.0.1/FFmpegTest.app/Contents/MacOS/YourExecutable` ?

Comment: I put it here: http://pastebin.com/g9Ubuvrt

Comment: I think the solution is to build ffmpeg without jack.

Comment: @MartinDelille either that, or bundle jack with your application.